# How Apache Reverse-Proxy to fix cross-domain

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I tried this:

Apache Config File:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www"
    ServerName 12.34.56.78
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://12.34.56.78:82"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://12.34.56.78:82"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:82>
    DocumentRoot "/www"
    ServerName 12.34.56.78:82
</VirtualHost>
```

And my Javascript/jQuery code is:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'http://12.34.56.78:80/',
        data:{},
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
           alert('success')
        },
        error : function() {  
           alert('error');
        }  
    });
```

Cross-domain problem still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 12.34.56.78
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass "/" "http://12.34.56.78:82"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://12.34.56.78:82"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:82>
    DocumentRoot "/www"
    ServerName 12.34.56.78:82
</VirtualHost>
```

And did you configured apache to listen on port 82? 
e.g.

```
Listen 82
```